# Not getting an "Enter Pin" prompt when pairing with BLE device

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I have a custom board that uses BLE to get Wifi credentials. I'm trying to pair with the board using my Pi.

I'm using `bluetoothctl`. Here's what I get when I try to pair:

```
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent is already registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent
Default agent request successful
[bluetooth]# pair f8:f0:05:75:5a:bf
Attempting to pair with F8:F0:05:75:5A:BF
[CHG] Device F8:F0:05:75:5A:BF Connected: yes
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed
[CHG] Device F8:F0:05:75:5A:BF Connected: no
[bluetooth]#
```

When I connect to this bluetooth device using the BLE scanner app on my phone, I'm prompted for a Pin, which I enter and it pairs no problem.

Do you know why I'm not getting prompted to enter a pin on my Pi?

Comment: Have a look here at the bit about turning `agent` of and on again: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41520644/1151724

Comment: No luck for me... Any other ideas?

Comment: Try `remove F8:F0:05:75:5A:BF` Then `trust F8:F0:05:75:5A:BF` then `pair F8:F0:05:75:5A:BF`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What has worked for me:

```
agent on
default-agent
power on
connect [mac-addr] (instead of pair [mac-addr])
```

The missing steps for me were `power on` and using `connect` instead of `pair`. Now it's working and my life is peachy.